# Update table column with count from rows in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm updating a count column in one table with the count of corresponding rows in another table like so, which seems to work fine.

```
UPDATE #Circuits  
SET CMLTotal = (SELECT COUNT(#UTCMLs.Drawing) 
                FROM #UTCMLs 
                WHERE #UTCMLs.DRAWING = #Circuits.DRAWING)
```

Now I need to include the rows from another table, #XRAYCMLs to get the total count of corresponding rows from both tables. I'm thinking UNION, but do not know how to make that happen.

How can I update my existing statement to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a better description of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just want `+` and two subqueries:

```
Update #Circuits
    SET CMLTotal = (select COUNT(u.Drawing)
                    from #UTCMLs u
                    where u.DRAWING = #Circuits.DRAWING
                   ) +
                   (select COUNT(#UTCMLs.Drawing)
                    from #XRAYCMLs x
                    where x.DRAWING = #Circuits.DRAWING
                   );
```